# Maven: Eclipse not correctly configuring paths in a project with a parent pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, parent-pom

I have a maven project that I correctly build through the command line (`mvn test`). It is structured this way:

```
pom.xml
|-------subdir1/pom.xml
|-------subdir2/pom.xml
|-------subdir3/pom.xml
```

Inside each of the subprojects dir (subdir[1-3]), I have a structure of:

```
src/main/java
src/test/java
```

When I import the project to Eclipse, or update the maven configuration (Alt-F5), the `src`dirs are *incorrectly* added to the BuildPath. I always need to manually remove them and add each one of the `java` dirs to have Eclipse correctly compiling.

How do configure my project so Eclipse will always correctly add the build paths?

Comment: I know, silly question, but are you using Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects, or Import > General > Existing Project into Workspace?

Comment: @MichaelPeacock: I'm using "Existing Maven Projects". No silly question, I'm new to Java World, there is probably something stupid I'm doing.

Comment: Ok. Just few guesses, 1) Check maven install used by eclipse. Make sure its at latest version or use the external installation. 2) Make sure JDK inside eclipse is the you expected. 3) Check settings.xml eclipse is pointing to. Make sure its same as the one used by command line.

Comment: @Shinchan: I've configured to use the external maven, but the problem persists. The /src dir is added every time I update  the maven (Alt-F5). The JDK and the settings.xml are the same.

Comment: Please paste portions of your root `pom.xml` and atleast 1 of the `subdir1/pom.xml` You can exclude dependencies to keep it small.

Comment: I can't paste properly what is required in the comment section and can't point what is wrong unless we see those pom.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ops, silly me. A colleague of mine added to the pom a spurious configuration:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

I just removed it from the configuration to use maven convention and everything worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a point, I used to get similar issues with eclipse while importing maven project, you can run this from cmd prompt `mvn eclipse:clean`  `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and then refresh or right click->maven->update your project in eclipse.

Also some times eclipse doesn`t import projects properly, you can just remove it from workspace and add again.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following in root pom.xml:-

```
    <modules>
            <module>subdir1</module>
            <module>subdir2</module>
            <module>subdir3</module>
    </modules>
```

Then in each of the subdirX/pom.xml add parent tag similar to the following. make sure parent coordinates are correct:

```
    <parent>
            <groupId>your-parent-groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>your-parent-artifactid</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your  and see it should not contain src folder.